# Generating Token By URL Request From ArcGIS Portal?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, token

I am able to create token from `Generate Token` operation on ArcGIS Portal Directory using IP Address of this request's origin parameter like [image]

```
but when I try to achive the token from URL like
https://map.geoca.com/portal/sharing/rest/generateToken?username=mapAdmin&password=psw&referer=https://map.geoca.com&f=json
```

I am getting this error message

> {"error":{"code":405,"messageCode":"GWM_0005","message":"Method not
>   supported.","details":[]}}

How can I fix this to get the token?

Answer (score 3):

By typing the request parameter in the URL, you are using the HTTP GET method to obtain the token. ArcGIS REST API states that only HTTP POST method is allowed. So the server replies with an error.

To place the request using the HTTP Post method, 
You can build the request using your favorite HTTP client:

- Build your HTML form
- Using curl
- Use Python (using requests library)
- etc..

Here are an examples of using python.

```
import requests

resp = requests.post("https://map.geoca.com/portal/sharing/rest/generateToken?f=json", 
    data={"username":"mapAdmin", "password":"pass123", 
        "referer":"https://map.geoca.com"})

print json.dumps(resp.json()["token"])
```

**Source:**
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Generate_Token/02r3000000m5000000/